# UIView над UINavigation bar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, navigationbar, uiview

Привет всем. 
Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на красную view закрывалась белая view, но красная вью должна быть на весь экран, а navigationBar она не закрывает.
Как сделать чтобы UIView была во весь экран, включая topbar.
Прятать navigaionBar нельзя, т.к. в последствии view будет не красная а прозрачная с эффектом тени.
Спасибо))[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скажу сразу что отображать `UIView` поверх `UINavigationBar` - это плохая идея. Для этого лучше подойдет `popup view controller`, но если очень надо то можно:

добавить subview в navigation bar:

```
guard let navigationBarView = navigationController?.view else { return }
navigationBarView.addSubview(yourSubview)
```

либо добавить `view` непосредственно в `main window`:

```
guard let mainWindowView = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow else { return }
mainWindowView.addSubview(yourSubview)
```

Comment: спасибо большое, способ с окном подходит. А почему плохая идея? представь что в белом окне какое то сообщение, а вместо красной вьюхи там тень или какой-то UIVisualEffect. и если этот эффект будет покрывать все кроме бара это будет ужасно смотреться

Comment: Нет, сама идея скрыть navigation bar нормальная. неправильно делать это с помощью sybview. Для этого придуман `popover view controller`. Причем он автоматически добавит эффект размытия и затемнения для заднего фона.